# android studio gives the "GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9 " error

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

When using Firestore Database on Firebase in Android Studio, it gives the error **"E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9"**, it does not write the data.
I changed the simulation a few times, but it didn't work.
Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It gives an error because Google Play services do not serve on virtual devices.
If you connect your Physical Device, you do not get an error.